# Read from .txt in sdcard and insert to edit text

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-edittext, android-sdcard

I made an android program where we(user) can set the id etc. from Edit Text and then that value will be saved into .txt file in sdcard. I already can do that (make a .txt file in sdcard. now I'm trying to read that .txt file in other activities in my application and insert that value in edit text there when this activities start/begin.. I need that so I can set for example "id" just one time in my application,, and then everytime user makes a form entries data, some data that set before for example "id" already insert into edit text in entries activities there..

**this is my code for insert value from edit text and make .txt file in sdcard:**

```
public class Setting extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button submit2;
    //private String filename = "AsriConfig.txt";
    //private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
    //File myInternalFile;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);


        //ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        //File directory = contextWrapper.getDir(filepath, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        //myInternalFile = new File(directory, filename);

     // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
        submit2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttom_submit2);
        submit2.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EditText agen2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agen2);

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttom_submit2 :
            try {
                File myFile = new File("/sdcard/myconfig.txt");
                myFile.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
                OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut); 
                myOutWriter.append(agen2.getText());
                myOutWriter.close();
                fOut.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data telah tersimpan..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            agen2.setText("");

            break;
            }
    }
```

and then this is my code in other activities for read value of .txt file from sdcard and automatically insert to Edit text where activities started:

```
public class CreateData extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    //inisilisasi elemen-elemen pada layout

    private String array_spinner[];
    private String array_spinner1[];

    private Button buttonSubmit;
    private EditText edAgen;
    private EditText edNo_kk;
    private EditText edNo_blanko;
    private EditText edNama;
    private EditText edAlamat;
    private EditText edJml_tertanggung;
    private Spinner edPilihan;
    private EditText edTelepon;
    private EditText edTertanggung1;
    private Spinner edStatus1;
    private EditText edTertanggung2;
    private Spinner edStatus2;
    private EditText edTertanggung3;
    private Spinner edStatus3;
    private EditText edTertanggung4;
    private Spinner edStatus4;
    private EditText edTertanggung5;
    private Spinner edStatus5;
    private EditText edTertanggung6;
    private Spinner edStatus6;

    private EditText edTertanggung7;
    private Spinner edStatus7;
    private EditText edTertanggung8;
    private Spinner edStatus8;
    private EditText edTertanggung9;
    private Spinner edStatus9;
    private EditText edTertanggung10;
    private Spinner edStatus10;

    //inisialisasi kontroller/Data Source
    private DBDataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_data);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);

        //File file = new File("/sdcard/myconfig.txt");

        String ret = "";

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("myconfig.txt");
            if (inputStream != null) {
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = "";
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            ret = text.toString();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        edAgen.setText(ret);

        buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttom_submit);
        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        edAgen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agen);
        edNo_kk = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.no_kk);
        edNo_blanko = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.no_blanko);
        edJml_tertanggung = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jml_tertanggung);
        edNama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nama);
        edAlamat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.alamat);

        array_spinner=new String[10];
        array_spinner[0]="A1";
        array_spinner[1]="A2";
        array_spinner[2]="A3";
        array_spinner[3]="A4";
        array_spinner[4]="A5";
        array_spinner[5]="B1";
        array_spinner[6]="B2";
        array_spinner[7]="B3";
        array_spinner[8]="B4";
        array_spinner[9]="B5";
        edPilihan = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pilihan_paket);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner);
        edPilihan.setAdapter(adapter);

        array_spinner1=new String[4];
        array_spinner1[0]=" ";
        array_spinner1[1]="SUAMI";
        array_spinner1[2]="ISTRI";
        array_spinner1[3]="ANAK";

        edStatus1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        edStatus2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus2.setAdapter(adapter2);

        edStatus3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status3);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus3.setAdapter(adapter3);

        edStatus4 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status4);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter4 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus4.setAdapter(adapter4);

        edStatus5 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status5);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter5 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus5.setAdapter(adapter5);

        edStatus6 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status6);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter6 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus6.setAdapter(adapter6);

        edStatus7 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status7);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter7 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus7.setAdapter(adapter7);

        edStatus8 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status8);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter8 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus8.setAdapter(adapter8);

        edStatus9 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status9);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter9 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus9.setAdapter(adapter9);

        edStatus10 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.status10);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter10 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        edStatus10.setAdapter(adapter10);

        edTelepon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telepon);
        edTertanggung1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung1);

        edTertanggung2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung2);

        edTertanggung3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung3);

        edTertanggung4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung4);

        edTertanggung5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung5);

        edTertanggung6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung6);

        edTertanggung7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung7);
        edTertanggung8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung8);
        edTertanggung9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung9);
        edTertanggung10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tertanggung10);

        // instanstiasi kelas DBDataSource
        dataSource = new DBDataSource(this);

        //membuat sambungan baru ke database
        dataSource.open();
    }

    //KETIKA Tombol Submit Diklik
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Inisialisasi data barang
        String agen = null;
        String no_kk = null;
        String no_blanko = null;
        String nama = null;
        String alamat = null;
        String jml_tertanggung = null;
        String pilihan = edPilihan.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String telepon = null;
        String tertanggung1 = null;
        String status1 = edStatus1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String tertanggung2 = null;
        String status2 = edStatus2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String tertanggung3 = null;
        String status3 = edStatus3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String tertanggung4 = null;
        String status4 = edStatus4.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String tertanggung5 = null;
        String status5 = edStatus5.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String tertanggung6 = null;
        String status6 = edStatus6.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String tertanggung7 = null;
        String status7 = edStatus7.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String tertanggung8 = null;
        String status8 = edStatus8.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String tertanggung9 = null;
        String status9 = edStatus9.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String tertanggung10 = null;
        String status10 = edStatus10.getSelectedItem().toString();
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")


        //inisialisasi barang baru (masih kosong)
        Barang barang = null;
        if(edAgen.getText()!=null && edNo_kk.getText()!=null && edNo_blanko.getText()!=null && edNama.getText()!=null && edAlamat.getText()!=null && edJml_tertanggung.getText()!=null && //edPilihan.getContext()!=null &&
                edTelepon.getText()!=null && 
                edTertanggung1.getText()!=null && //edStatus1.getText()!=null && 
                edTertanggung2.getText()!=null && //edStatus2.getText()!=null && 
                edTertanggung3.getText()!=null && //edStatus3.getText()!=null && 
                edTertanggung4.getText()!=null && //edStatus4.getText()!=null && 
                edTertanggung5.getText()!=null && //edStatus5.getText()!=null && 
                edTertanggung6.getText()!=null &&
                edTertanggung7.getText()!=null &&
                edTertanggung8.getText()!=null &&
                edTertanggung9.getText()!=null &&
                edTertanggung10.getText()!=null) //edStatus6.getText()!=null)
        {
            /* jika field nama, merk, dan harga tidak kosong
             * maka masukkan ke dalam data barang*/
            agen = edAgen.getText().toString();
            no_kk = edNo_kk.getText().toString();
            no_blanko = edNo_blanko.getText().toString();
            nama = edNama.getText().toString();
            alamat = edAlamat.getText().toString();
            jml_tertanggung = edJml_tertanggung.getText().toString();
            //pilihan = edPilihan.getContext().toString();
            telepon = edTelepon.getText().toString();
            tertanggung1 = edTertanggung1.getText().toString();
            //status1 = edStatus1.getText().toString();
            tertanggung2 = edTertanggung2.getText().toString();
            //status2 = edStatus2.getText().toString();
            tertanggung3 = edTertanggung3.getText().toString();
            //status3 = edStatus3.getText().toString();
            tertanggung4 = edTertanggung4.getText().toString();
            //status4 = edStatus4.getText().toString();
            tertanggung5 = edTertanggung5.getText().toString();
            //status5 = edStatus5.getText().toString();
            tertanggung6 = edTertanggung6.getText().toString();
            //status6 = edStatus6.getText().toString();
            tertanggung7 = edTertanggung7.getText().toString();
            tertanggung8 = edTertanggung8.getText().toString();
            tertanggung9 = edTertanggung9.getText().toString();
            tertanggung10 = edTertanggung10.getText().toString();

        }   

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.buttom_submit:
                // insert data barang baru
                barang = dataSource.createBarang(agen, no_kk, no_blanko, nama, alamat, jml_tertanggung, pilihan, telepon, tertanggung1, status1, tertanggung2, status2, tertanggung3, status3, tertanggung4, status4, tertanggung5, status5, tertanggung6, status6, tertanggung7, status7, tertanggung8, status8, tertanggung9, status9, tertanggung10, status10);

                Intent z = new Intent(this, Otorisasi.class);
                startActivity(z);
                CreateData.this.finish();
                //konfirmasi kesuksesan
                Toast.makeText(this, "masuk Entri\n" +
                        "id_agen:" + barang.getAgen() +
                        "no_kk:" + barang.getNo_kk() +
                        "no_blanko:" + barang.getNo_blanko() +
                        "nama:" + barang.getNama() +
                        "alamat:" + barang.getAlamat() +
                        "jml_tertanggung:" + barang.getJml_tertanggung() +
                        "pilihan:" + barang.getPilihan_paket() +
                        "telepon:" + barang.getTelepon() +
                        "tertanggung1:" + barang.getTertanggung1() +
                        "status1:" + barang.getStatus1() +
                        "tertanggung2:" + barang.getTertanggung2() +
                        "status2:" + barang.getStatus2() +
                        "tertanggung3:" + barang.getTertanggung3() +
                        "status3:" + barang.getStatus3() +
                        "tertanggung4:" + barang.getTertanggung4() +
                        "status4:" + barang.getStatus4() +
                        "tertanggung5:" + barang.getTertanggung5() +
                        "status5:" + barang.getStatus5() +
                        "tertanggung6:" + barang.getTertanggung6() +
                        "status6:" + barang.getStatus6(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;

        }
    }
```

Please look into variable agen and edAgen.. I try set that field from value in .txt file

Answer (score 1):

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtText" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

And your code will look like this:

```
//Find the directory for the SD Card using the API
//*Don't* hardcode "/sdcard"
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

//Get the text file
File file = new File(sdcard,"file.txt");

//Read text from file
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
    br.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    //You'll need to add proper error handling here
}

//Find the view by its id
EditText edtText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtText);

//Set the text
edtText.setText(text);
```

Comment: thx man,, i apreciate. but when i use hint in my edit text xml, the text which appear is my hint not the value in file .txt